# Load data from database to string

Tags: c#, sql, string, oracle

I'm trying at the moment to get an information from a database and want to save it in a string, but yeah not sure about how really to do it right.

This is my code, where I open the LoadSql function:

```
public void LoadData(string KNR, string WNR, String filter)
{
    // WHERE
    const string sqlTemplate = "SELECT KUNDENAUFTRAGSNR FROM MESSFELD.AUSSTANDSDATEN WHERE FTNR = '" + txt_Barcode_read.Text + "'";
    string sql = string.Format(sqlTemplate, filter);

    Database cdb = new Database();

    // try to connect and cancel on error
    if (!cdb.Open("**********", "*********"))
    {
        SetStatusText("Datenbank ist nicht verfügbar.");
        return;
    }

    WNR = cdb.LoadSql(sql);
    cdb.Close();
}
```

And here is the `LoadSQL` function:

```
public DataTable LoadSql(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, _con);
        command.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;

        OracleDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);

        return dt;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For the moment the `LoadSQL` is saving in datatable, how to change for saving the number in the string WNR?

Comment: is this a parameterization question? what is the value of `filter`, and what is the expected output from the `string.Format`? note that you **should not** put user input directly into SQL - you should use parameters, but if you confirm that's what is tripping you up, I'm sure we can help more. Also: `WNR` is a *local parameter* - updating this value will have no effect whatsoever on the calling code, so: you'd probably want to show the calling code here so we can understand what you're trying to do; I'm guessing `return theNewString;` is probably closer to what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-write your `LoadSQL` function to something like this :

```
public string LoadSql(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, _con);
        command.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;

        OracleDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        
        if(rdr.HasRows)
            return rdr.GetString(0);
        else
            return "";
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```